# Error in importing SQL dump from server to local

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, mysql, mysql-error-1064

So I've exported a dump from my ovh running mysql 5.5.41-0+wheezy1 and phpmyadmin 3.4.11.1deb2+deb7u1.

I'm using wampserver locally with mysql 5.6.17 (and the last release 5.6.27 sometimes) community server and phpmyadmin 4.1.14.

I successfully imported my dump into my 5.3.17 and 5.6.17 DB using phpmyadmin 4.1.14, but using phpmyadmin 4.5.0.2 (the last release) both imports fail with mysql error 1064 - error in your SQL syntax...

I tried back and forth with different combinations of versions and it is definitively phpmyadmin 4.5.0.2 causing the problem here, in my opinion.

I really liked the new UI in the last release and would like to stick with it, but not if it's source of errors with mysql.

Does anybody have some ideas on this bug ?

in my dump there's nothing particular except that the import crash during a wordpress table (pretty old wordpress version I think because the server is an old one used by each school student union webmaster over the years)

thanks a lot

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11542 so you could try the patch that has been merged (will be part of 4.5.1).

Comment: possible, I'll test asap. thanks I'll keep you posted

Comment: yep that definitively solved my problem. well done for identifying so quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed for the upcoming 4.5.1 version, see github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11542.